# Writing application for Windows Mobile 6.1 options?

Tags: java, c++, c, windows, mobile

What can I use to write application for Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5?
Application was written before (not by me) using VB.Net 2008, but I really would like to move away from it to plain C/C++ or possibly Java.

Where can I start and what are my options? I don't have much experience with working with Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are several options which you may choose from.**

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677133.aspx

Note: Java is not on this list and cannot be used for app development in Windows mobile.

Comment: Although I didn't downvote and this question is offtopic anyway some of the downvotes may be because you didn't say why or how Visual C++ may help the OP. This is one of many reasons why questions asking to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic. Theres likely to end up a whole load of different recomendations and to justify which is best would take a huge post to justify or its just an opinion

Comment: @Richard Tingle Edited answer to remove recommendation of Visual C++ and only provide list of languages that can be used to write apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In the end I installed Visual Studio 2008 Pro and doing development in C#.